# Read Undelivered email body in C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, outlook-2010

I am developing one tool to keep track of emails and would like to trace the emails undelivered to sender.
I dont want to use any third party tool or any external reference

What I have tried?
-To read report Item but Body is in Chinese like language
-Googled on some solutions but nothing is working i.e. solution is related to

//PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS 
 link to get property name "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001F"
 outlook PropertyAccessor class

PropName link is not working anymore.

Could anyone here please help me I would like to get from which sender the email delivery is failed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show what you have got so far.

Comment: Do you mean you are getting garbage from the ReportItem.Body property? It is a known problem in OOM. The only workarounds are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thanks for your reply,my issue is I  can not register any DLL on client machine. How do I use Redemption can you please give me example?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am getting some garbage from ReportItem.body property, I can delete ReportItem from Inbox but can not read it do you have some idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the 'PropertyAccessor'?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev : Yes but not able to get the email id  on which delivery is failed.

Comment: What is the error when you attempt to register the dll?

Comment: @Dmitry I didn't registered it require lot of approvals to register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property contains the same Diagnostic information shown in the body. You just need to read it using the `PropertyAccessor` class and parse the string with `From` and `To` entries.

```
  Outlook.PropertyAccessor oPA = reportItem.PropertyAccessor;
  string transportHeaders = (string)oPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E");
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene for reply but I would like to fetch for ReportItem (UnDelivered report)

Comment: The same can be used for the  report item.

Comment: I am able to fecth the information but it only gives me the address of the sender i.e. mailserver address but not the email id for whiich delivery is failed.

Comment: Thanks for the help issue is resolved I am able to get address now edited the asnwer.